# Testing a parachute for a Mars landing using a wind tunnel at hypersonic speed and Martian pressure?

Tags: testing, parachute

The parachute for the Mars Science Laboratory (with the Curiosity rover) was tested in the NASA Ames Research Center 80 by 120 Foot Wind Tunnel.

[image]

The wind tunnel is currently capable of air speeds up to 100 knots (190 km/h; 120 mph). But how was the parachute tested with a speed and pressure similar to a real entry to Mars? Only by scaling speed and air viscosity or by using a smaller model parachute instead of the original size?

Picture and speed data from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ames_Research_Center).

Answer (score 5):

The full scale wind tunnel testing did not attempt to duplicate Martian conditions.

The purpose of the full scale testing was to to

> provide  an  end  to  end  test  of  the  parachute  system  from 
>   mortar  fire  to  parachute  inflation.

and

> initial  inflation  strength  qualification

Much more detail about subscale wind tunnel testing and other parachute tests can be found in the paper [Overview of the Mars Science Laboratory Parachute Decelerator Subsystem](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.666.3402&rep=rep1&type=pdf).  A sample:

> a  multi-phase  delta  qualification  by  analysis  and  subscale  supersonic  wind  tunnel  test  program  to  address  the  fundamental 
>   physics  of  the  supersonic  operation  of DGB  parachutes  as  a
>   function  of  Mach  number , parachute  size,  and capsule  wake 
>   interaction.  The first  phase  is  computational fluid  dynamics 
>   (CFD)  of  a  2%  scale  rigid  parachute  canopy and  capsule 
>   validated  by  a  2%  scale wind  tunnel test  of  the  rigid 
>   configuration  over  the  MSL  Mach and  Re  number  deployment 
>   range  in  the  Ames  9x7  ft.  unitary  tunnel.  Phase  two  is
>   fluid  structure  interaction  (FSI)  analysis  of  a  flexible 
>   canopy  with  capsule  validated  by  5%  scale  wind  tunnel  tests
>   over  the  MSL  deployment  Mach  and Re  range  in  the  GRC 
>   10x 10  ft.  unitary  tunnel.  The  final  phase  is  the 
>   application  of  the  validated  FSI  tools  to  the  prediction  of 
>   the  full  scale  para chute  performance  in  Mars  type  deployment 
>   conditions  providing  predictions  of  supersonic  drag 
>   performance,  stability,  and  canopy  loading.

DGB = **D**isk **G**ap **B**and

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same forces to the parachute at high speed and very low pressure (marsian conditions) and low speed and a pressure of about 1 bar (conditions in the wind tunnel)?

Comment: @Uwe: if you had unlimited budget, a lot of things are "possible". The parachute engineers did what they judged to be the most practical given their engineering and budgetary constraints.

Comment: @Uwe, some of the historical NASA wind tunnels were sealed to allow operation at a range of pressures to compensate for scale effects, so supersonic and pressure adjusted tunnels exist but have not found a users guide or similar listing the current tunnels and capabilities.

Comment: @GremlinWranger But the photo I used in the question does not like a sealed wind tunnel that may be used at a pressure much smaller or greater than ambient pressure. The wall shown would not resist the forces of a larger pressure difference.

Comment: @Uwe, not my field but agree, presence of humans suggest this is at earth pressures and relatively low speeds, but done because it is the best achievable test of the flight hardware with technology available to NASA per Organic Marble's answer. The inability to fully test is mentioned as a major risk for Insight in the quote here https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/32262/why-is-insights-nylon-parachute-a-soft-good. Possible complication with closed tunnels for this specific test is that deployment probably produces a bunch of debris that risks damage a closed tunnel fan system.